# If $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable, and $|f'(x)| < 1$ for all $x$, is $f$ a contraction?

Tags: real-analysis

As the title says. I can see that this is a weak contraction, and my intuition tells me that I can find a counterexample to prove that it need not be a contraction, but so far such a counterexample has eluded me. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One counterexample is $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+1}$.

The derivative is less than $1$, but you can make it as close to $1$ as you want by making $x$ big enough.  Thus there is no number $c<1$ such that the derivative remains less than $c$.

Comment: . . . . and also: notice that this function has no fixed point.

Comment: Hello Michael Hardy, can I ask you something about the derivative being less than 1?

Comment: @Linda : Only if you're specific.

Comment: how would a function whose first derivative in absolute value is less than 1 look like? I know that the slope of the tangent of any point of its domain is less than 1, but yet I can not imagine how the function would look like, is there any specific function whose first derivative is less than 1,so I can create an image of how the graphic of such function would look like?

Comment: @Linda : This curve is half of a hyperbola with the lines $y=\pm x$ as asymptotes. Consider what happens if $x=1\text{ million}.$ If you had $y = \sqrt{x^2},$ that would just be $y = |x|,$ but you have $y= \sqrt{x^2+1} = \sqrt{(1\text{ million})^2 + 1},$ and the ${}+1$ is almost nothing compared to the $1\text{ million},$ so its very close to $y=x$ at that point. So it should be plausible that $y=x$ is an asymptote. It's not hard to figure out what this graph looks like. But if you have specific questions aobut that, you should be specific. Your comment above says$\,\ldots \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots,$you're wondering about its derivative being less than $1.$ If that's what your question is about, then have you actually found its derivative?

Comment: Yeah that's clear thanks a lot. But I actually asked for functions in general not for this specific function.So is there any property that functions whose first derivative in absolute value is less than 1 must have, so how does the graphic of these kinda functions differ compared to functions whose first derivative in absolute value is greater than 1?

Comment: @Linda : It just means the graph never gets too steep.

Comment: Yeah I get it now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

For $x\ne y$ we have $f(x)-f(y)=(x-y)f'(\xi)$ for some $\xi$ betwee $x$ andd $y$ by the MWT, hence $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y|\cdot |f'(\xi)|<|x-y|$.
However, $|f'|$ need not have any bound $k<1$, hence will in general only be a weak contraction (aka. non-expansive map).

*Example:*
$$ f(x)= x-\arctan x$$
has $f'(x)\to 1$ as $x\to \pm\infty$.

Comment: I presume you meant "MVT".